# Django annotate by looking up a related field value

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a package sorting system in Django. I need to look up the `"sort code"` of a set of `"barcodes"` This code works:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    Zip = CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)


class Barcode(models.Model):
    barcode = CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    Order = ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class SortCode(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class SortZip(models.Model):
    zipcode = CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    sortcode = ForeignKey('SortCode', null=True, default=None, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)



sortzip = SortZip.objects.filter(zipcode=OuterRef('Order__Zip'))
barcodes = Barcode.objects.annotate(sortcode_value=Subquery(sortzip.values('sortcode__name')))
```

However, `SortZip.zipcode` only stores 5-digit zip codes, and `Order.Zip` sometimes contains zip+4, so I need to look up the `SortZip` from only the first 5 digits of `Order.Zip`:

```py
sortzip = SortZip.objects.filter(zipcode=OuterRef('Order__Zip')[:5])
barcodes = Barcode.objects.annotate(sortcode_value=Subquery(sortzip.values('sortcode__name')))
```

This causes the following error:

```
TypeError: 'OuterRef' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried adding the following property to the `Order` model and using the property:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    Zip = CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def Zip5(self):
       return self.Zip[:5]
...

sortzip = SortZip.objects.filter(zipcode=OuterRef('Order__Zip5'))
barcodes = Barcode.objects.annotate(sortcode_value=Subquery(sortzip.values('sortcode__name')))
```

However, this gives a different error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'Zip5' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of truncate string is using `Left` function.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Left

sortzip = SortZip.objects.filter(zipcode=OuterRef(Left('order__zip', 5)))
```